# No solution for 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with an MVC C# application in one controller.

The following code continues to give the error:

```
 *The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.*
```

The code below:

```
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory("~/App_Data/uploads/" + tempName);
var usersForImport = from c in excel.Worksheet<User>()
                        select c;
int count = usersForImport.Count();

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    User user = new User();
    user = usersForImport.Skip(i).First();
    db.Users.Add(user);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I have tried 2 solutions from previous posts, as I thought this problem was identical, but they do not solve the problem.

The two solutions I have tried are to install the Microsoft Access Database Engine or set the target platform for x86.

The code relies on 'linqtoexcel' package.

Has anyone else run into these problems? Any solutions?

Comment: You might want to tell us about the solutions you've tried and dismissed. Or at the very least link to them. And please give your post a decent title.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise I had set a bad title but have included what I have tried

Comment: Is your application an ASP.NET app?

Comment: The application is an MVC C# application

Comment: And it is running in a 32-bit app pool?  Don't use ACE on a web server, it is not made to scale.

Comment: That's what I am confused about. I use a SQL server and am confused why there is an Access connection? I assume it is something to do with the ExceltoLINQ package I am using. I am not too sure how to set an app pool on a development machine, the machine where the debug is happening is 64-bit

Comment: https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel has documented that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For 64-bit apps, there are two versions of the ACE driver available:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734 for Office 2007

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255 for Office 2010

I believe the Office 2007 version has the ProgId 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', so I would try this one rather than Office 2010, which I believe has the ProgId 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.14.0'.

From your description, it looks like the linqtoexcel package might depend on the Office 2007 version.

Comment: You right. It work on 2007. I'm already install 2010 not work. after that change to 2007. it work. thank

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this in properties of the project, in the Build Tab.
I have changed the platform target from x64 to x86